# Is it possible to downgrade a reference Version? (SQLite to be precise)

Tags: visual-studio, sqlite, visual-studio-2015, uwp, reference

So I had to download `SQLite for Universal Windows Platform(SQLite.UWP.2015, Version=3.25.1)`

Is it possible to dowgrade to Version `3.24.0`?

Comment: which issue do you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can choose which version of package to be installed in Nuget Package manager while installing. Look at screenshot below

[image]

**Please Note:** 
Always install latest version..